# Book with reference to Scientology

Tags: story-identification

Recently I read something about Scientology. I remember having read about it before, in some SciFi novel. Thing is, all I can remember was that this:

- There was one dialogue about Scientology.
- The dialogue explained the general practice, and also gave an example of some lady (their disciple) who was tortured or something.

At first, I though it was *Contact*, but I don't think that there's a Scientology reference there. Might be a Michael Crichton book, but I can't figure out which.

I also remember that the book was good, but can't remember any details of the plot.

Comment: You might have better luck with this in Chat; list questions are discouraged -- this has a Story-Identification question, but ends with a list request.  I wouldn't be terribly surprised to see votes closing it shortly.  Rephrasing it might help. :)

Comment: @KeithHWeston: I don't think Manishearth is asking for a list, I think he's asking about a *specific book*.

Comment: @Wikis - That's why I suggested he re-phrase it slightly; it's ending with "...if you list as many books as you can remember with..."; phrasing like that usually triggers a somewhat negative response.  Just my suggestion; I think it will get him better responses to the main question here, and, failing that, a better list from chat.

Comment: @KeithHWeston: yeah, you're right. I will edit, well spotted!

Comment: Ok, no issue about the list... Basically I was saying if there are multiple books, list as many you can think of..

Comment: Please add more details to this. I know you might not have much, but we really need more details if we are to have any chance of figuring this one out...

Comment: I don't have much.. I was hoping if someone could recollect any such book, there's the chance that it'd be recognizable. I do have a feeling that the book was similar to Contact, but I'm not sure of this. The similarity might just be the extremely tiny print used in both books.

Comment: When did you maybe read the book?  Where and what language did you acquire the book in?

Comment: A year or two ago. English.

Comment: We've ruled out Battlefield Earth?

Comment: Yup. First thing I found on the net.. Not it..

Comment: You mentioned not knowing anything about the plot.. How about the cover?  You'd be surprised how often a cover description can trigger someone's memory.  Single color?  Specific image?  Certain style?  Whatever you can remember can help.

Comment: Does L. Ron Hubbard explicitly mention Scientology in any of his science fiction?

Comment: @Sam I'm, curious as well.

Comment: Was the disciple tortured by others or by Scientologists?  It might have been referring to [Lisa McPherson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisa_McPherson).

Comment: There is a book called the Mind Game by Norman Spinard which dealt extensively with cults (and briefly mentions scientology), but focuses on a scientology-esque religion

Comment: @Manishearth: You said, "Recently I read something about Scientology". What was the gist of this? And, did the book you're looking for mention Scientology by name or just describe a similar fictional religion?

Comment: With so little information, this is not a story identification question. “Book with a dialogue about Scientology” is far from being a unique characterization.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's the specific one you're talking about, but *On Basilisk Station* includes a brief description of the faiths of the bridge officers, one of whom is a 2nd Reformation Scientologist.  As far as I can remember, no further information is given.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but thats not it :(

Answer (score 1):

There is a reference to scientology in the 1972 film " The Terminal Man" based on a Michael Crichton novel. There is also a reference in the book "Audrey Rose" by Frank De Fellita, which is a novel about reincarnation ( the main character meets a scientologist at one point who does believe in reincarnation )